# Algorithm to find all sundays on given a range year

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, logic, pseudocode

how to find all sundays from given date between march 2016 - march 2018. with looping, there are 3 loops : looping for year, month, and date, then use if.
But im confuse about looping. can you help me ?

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: Bite off one thing at a time.  If you don't understand loops, don't complicate it by also choosing a problem that you don't know how to express.  First, learn looping and practice it with simpler problems.  Put actual code in your question for what your current attempt is.

Comment: thats my assignment from my mentor, not my choice.. :D  `for(int year = 2016; year<=2018;year++) for(int month=march;month<=december;month++) then looping for searching start and end date, if day = sunday then print. day =day +1`

Comment: Your mentor must be mental or you must have been mid-understood him. The easiest way is to: find the first Sunday in the interval and keep adding 7 days to that time-point until you get past the end date of the interval, transforming those timepoints into their corresponding date of the calendar,

Comment: my mentor just test my logic, but my problem just to know how to write loop date, from march 2016 to march 2018.

Comment: you need to create table of number of days per each month ... like `const int days[2][12]={ {31,28,31,30,...}, {31,29,31,30,...}};` and use that as the limit for the 3th `for` loop for starters like `for (day=0;day<days[y][month];day++)` where `y` is `0` for normal year and `1` for every `4th` and `1000th` except every `100th` ...

Comment: need to create table? not like this `for (day>=31march2018)`

Comment: or `for(date=0;date<=tdays;date++)`

Comment: no because you do not know how big `tdays` is until you complete the loops ... on top of the 3 loops you just need to add day in the week `diw` counter in the inner most loop like `for (day=0;day<days[y][month];day++,diw=(diw+1)%7)` where you init it before loops with the actual day `(monday,....)` of the first iterated date.  and inside the loops just add if that increment the number of Sundays if `diw==6`

Comment: **TimeDate** routines usually use `epoch` which is some specific known date (with known things like day in week, Julian date etc) from which it increments and count all stuff.  (you can increment by any amount of days if you do it properly not just +1). Threre are also some algos out there which can avoid use of epoch up to some point usually used in astronomy SW

Comment: If you want to avoid tables you can still use 13 if statements instead .... but that is ugly and slow not to mention hugely more code then just 3-6 lines for the whole thing

Comment: is it true like this? some logic algorithm 
`for (int year = 2016; year<=2018; year++)
 for (int month = march; month<=december; month++)
  while (day <= 31 month) do
  if day = sunday then
   println (date)
   day = day + 1

  end if
     end while
  end loop
end loop`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a good date library [like this one](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  But that's probably not what your mentor is looking for.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    for (sys_days start = mar/sun[1]/2016; start <= sys_days{mar/last/2018};
                                           start += weeks{1})
        std::cout << start << '\n';
}

2016-03-06
2016-03-13
2016-03-20
...
2018-03-18
2018-03-25
```

Comment: thats the good simple one, but my mentor want me to use 3 loops from year, month and date like this : `for (int year = 2016; year<=2018; year++)
 for (int month = march; month<=december; mont++)
  while (day <= 31 month) do
  if day = sunday then
   println (date)
   day = day + 1

  end if
     end while
  end loop
end loop`